# Where to download Silverlight Chess Sample?

Tags: silverlight

Where to download the source for Silverlight chess sample by Microsoft?

http://www.silverlight.net/content/samples/sl2/silverlightchess/run/default.html

I can't find anything in Microsoft's resource center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jstegman/archive/2009/09/08/silverlight-3-sample-updates.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The source code for that sample was never publicly released.

Have you tried downloading the XAP locally and using Reflector/DotPeek/ILSpy to reverse engineer it?

Comment: Are you sure? Because I've seen a Windows Phone 7 port for it. How could someone port it without the source?